# How to find similar email ids with mysql or php?

Tags: php, mysql

There is a website that provides referral points to the signed-in user. In order to get the points, people are using genuine email IDs (say in Gmail) with a single dot added in various places of the email address. Pasted below are some samples of this case. If this kind of data is present already in the MySQL database by various other users, how to identify this. My SQL Query or PHP code snippet will be helpful.

```
si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4.52.2@gmail.com
si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4.522@gmail.com
si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.45.2.2@gmail.com
si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.45.22@gmail.com
si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4522@gmail.com
```

There are more different email ids like that.

EDIT : Requesting the downvoters to provide the reason also.

Comment: use this `$email = str_replace('.', '', $email);`

Comment: If you have verified each of them emails then they are genuine, your need to work out other means to detect cheating.

Comment: You are fighting a losing battle here. Many email providers allow for the use of dots (like Gmail) or flags where you can add "+something" between the username and @ symbol to create pseudo addresses which route to the same address. You may be better off getting users to authenticate with your system by signing up using their Google/Twitter/Facebook account.

Comment: Thanks, Luke, What if they create email ids again with the similar pattern just to get the points? They can still able to signup successfully and claim it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`similar_text()`](https://php.net/similar_text) to check if a string is similar to another.

The function below, will return `true` if `$to_test` has any entry similar at 80% or more.

```
$values = [
'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4.52.2@gmail.com',
'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4.522@gmail.com',
'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.45.2.2@gmail.com',
'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.45.22@gmail.com',
'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4522@gmail.com',
];

function has_similar($to_test, $values, $similar = 80) {
    $perc = 0 ;
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        similar_text($value, $to_test, $perc);
        if ($perc > $similar) return true ;
    }
    return false ;
}

var_dump(has_similar('sit.i.a.m.in14522@gmail.com', $values)); // true
var_dump(has_similar('another-mail@example.com', $values)); // false
```

Will outputs:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable in php

```
$email = 'sitiamin14522@gmail.com';
$email = explode('@', $email);
```

then query is like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT email
        FROM user
        WHERE
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1), ".", "") = "'.$email[0].'"';
```

**updated as user requested, only SQL to search duplicated email**

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1), '.', ''), '@', 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)) AS email_replaced,
       COUNT(email) as total_duplicated
FROM user
GROUP BY email_replaced
```

Comment: is there a way this query can be altered to check the records in the table itself? As of now I wouldn't know how much such duplicates will be there.

Comment: Is your database email only gmail.com or there any other domain email?

Comment: Other domains as well.

Comment: I have updated the answer, refresh it

Comment: Thanks but total_duplicated is always 1.

Comment: So there is no duplicated email, do you have the data?

Comment: have slightly modified your query and posted it as the answer that gives the as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Rendi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9483563/rendi-wahyudi-muliawan) answer, have arrived query as below that would give me the count of duplicates.

```
SELECT email,count(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1), ".", "")) as counted
        FROM test
    group by REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1), ".", "")
        having counted > 5
    order by counted desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using an regular expression pattern to identify cheating characters.

For example, this code snippet does the job as you described it in your question. In other words, this could be extended, if you have advanced needs for cheating characters (`$addresses` is the array, which holds all the e-mail addresses to check for duplication and `$uniqueAddresses` is the array with only unique addresses):

```
$addresses = array(
    'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4.52.2@gmail.com',
    'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4.522@gmail.com',
    'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.45.2.2@gmail.com',
    'mitest@example.com',
    'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.45.22@gmail.com',
    'si.t.i.a.m.i.n1.4522@gmail.com',
    'my.test@examle.com',
    'mi.test@example.com'
);

foreach ($addresses as &$address) {
    $lastPos = strrpos($address, '@');
    $namePart = substr($address, 0, $lastPos);
    $domainPart = substr($address, $lastPos + 1);

    $address = preg_replace($cheatPattern, '', $namePart) . $domainPart;
}

$uniqueAddresses = array_unique($addresses);
```

Answer (score -3):

If it's "si.t.i.a.m.i.n1" you're looking for, there's a very easy solution within MySql.

select * from {table name} where email like '%si.t.i.a.m.i.n1%'

I would reccomend to base on IP adresses and not email adresses

Comment: thanks but I would't know the exact phrases like that

Comment: nope. It is just a wildcard around the string `si.t.i.a.m.i.n1`. So, it could be anything around. But the inside check doesn't work.

Comment: The thing is, you phrased it exactly the same on all those email adresses, you should start looking into a IP adress solution.